# Bootstrap 3 seems to justify table columns differently depending on the size of the field

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, haml

I have a simple table styled with bootstrap but for some reason it will use different justify depending on how long the fields are.  There seems to be 2 different settings.

1. If the line data is short, it will left justify right next to the first cell and keep both fields short.
2. If the data is long, as in more than what would fit in one line, it will right block justify.

I wonder if there's a was to just chose #2 justify? I do have the entire table inside of a panel.

The code for just the panel-body looks like this, in HAML:

```
.panel-heading
  %h3.panel-title Case Information
%table.panel-body.table
  - unless current_user.one_user?
    - unless current_user.another_user?
      %tr.col-md-12
        %th.col-md-3 Patient Name
        %td.col-md-9= patient_full_name

      %tr.col-md-12
        %th.col-md-3 Patient Date of Birth
        %td.col-md-9= patient_birthdate

    %tr.col-md-12
      %th.col-md-3 Patient Age
      %td.col-md-9= patient_age

    %tr.col-md-12
      %th.col-md-3 Patient Gender
      %td.col-md-9= patient_gender

 -unless kase.medical_history.nil?
   %tr.col-md-12
     %th.col-md-3 Medical History
     %td.col-md-9= simple_format medical_history

 -unless kase.medications.nil?
   %tr.col-md-12
     %th.col-md-3 Medications
     %td.col-md-9= simple_format medications
```

This is what it looks like with short data:
[image: Short data fields table]

This is what it looks like with long data:
[image: Long data fields table]

You notice that the long fields are in some sort of block justification? I would like the right table column to all line up as if they were all long data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did a small test on my computer and see if removing ".col-md-12" from the %tr fixes the alignment issue.

Comment: @Jase Perfect, that did it, thanks! You may want to add your comment as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this as a comment instead of an answer so here it is: I did a small test on my computer and see if removing ".col-md-12" from the %tr fixes the alignment issue.

Comment: This was actually the correct answer. Thanks. I don't know why I got carried away with the col-md's.